# Stripe integration with NET 6

Tags: .net-core, stripe-payments

I have an app written in .NET 6. My backend correctly calls to Stripe, but I receive this error:

> You requested an account link for an account that is not connected to your platform or does not exist.

My request and response body:

**Response body**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "You requested an account link for an account that is not connected to your platform or does not exist.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_OICDzVOzQ4exfq?t=1682416666",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

**Request POST body**

```
{
  "account": "acct_1MxqQePedstesTv",
  "return_url": "configure-payment",
  "type": "account_onboarding",
  "refresh_url": "configure-payment"
}
```

I'm using this NuGet package for Stripe: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net/41.14.0-beta.3

Any idea what is wrong? I can't find anything about my error.

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is that you're passing a wrong account ID, either your platform's account, or an account that isn't connected to your platform.

Please check the [request log](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_OICDzVOzQ4exfq?t=1682416666) on your dashboard to see which account ID you're passing.

Generally speaking, you need to first create an account and use that account ID to create an Account Link.

Comment: I'm creating a web app and want people with existing accounts to be able to be linked to my stripe account so I can transfer funds to their accounts. Do you know how I would be able to accomplish this?